# automapper: mapping depend on other properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two objects:

```
public class Info
{
   public string ArtificialPerson {get; set;}
   ...
}

public class DtoInfo
{
   public string FullName {get; set;}
   public bool IsLegal {get; set;}
}
```

I want to do the following, if `IsLegal` is true then map `FullName` to `ArtificialPerson`. How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set some mapping configuration:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<DtoInfo, Info>().ForMember(info => info.ArtificialPerson, configExpr => 
        { 
            configExpr.MapFrom(dtoInfo => dtoInfo.FullName);
            configExpr.Condition((DtoInfo dtoInfo) => dtoInfo.IsLegal);
        });

        var info1 = Mapper.Map<Info>(new DtoInfo
        {
            FullName = "Lemons",
            IsLegal = true
        });

        Console.WriteLine(info1.ArtificialPerson); // displays "Lemons"

        var info2 = Mapper.Map<Info>(new DtoInfo
        {
            FullName = "Cocaine",
            IsLegal = false
        });

        Console.WriteLine(info2.ArtificialPerson); // displays null string
```